# Make Canvas to follow the camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, menu, virtual-reality

I want an UI canvas to follow the camera so it will be in front of the head always and also interactable like VR menu. I'm using the following code to do so.

```
public class FollowMe : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject menuCanvas;
    public Camera FirstPersonCamera;
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float smoothFactor = 0.5f;

// how far to stay away fromt he center

    public float offsetRadius   = 0.3f;
    public float distanceToHead = 4;

    public  void Update()
    {
        // make the UI always face towards the camera
        menuCanvas.transform.rotation = FirstPersonCamera.transform.rotation;

        var cameraCenter = FirstPersonCamera.transform.position + FirstPersonCamera.transform.forward * distanceToHead;

        var currentPos = menuCanvas.transform.position;

        // in which direction from the center?
        var direction = currentPos - cameraCenter;

        // target is in the same direction but offsetRadius
        // from the center
        var targetPosition = cameraCenter + direction.normalized * offsetRadius;

        // finally interpolate towards this position
        menuCanvas.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPos, targetPosition, smoothFactor);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the canvas is flickering in front fo the camera and it is not properly positioned. How do I make the menu to follow the camera?|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no reason against it you can use a `ScreenSpace - Camera` canvas as stated [in the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html). Then you can reference your FPS camera as the rendering camera for the canvas.

Comment: Unfortnately it has to be in world space as it has to follow the Player

Comment: Would it be an option to make the canvas a child of the player GameObject in the hierarchy, then offset it wherever you want it to follow?

Comment: I have created an empty GameObject. The menu canvas is the child of the Player Gameobject. This script is attached to the player game object but still, I can't get the exact transform; :(

Comment: Please clarify > I can't get the exact transform.  
Also what is the empty gameobject? Could you edit your question to include the gameobject hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do this is using Screen Space - Camera mode which you can setup from Canvas component and in Render Mode properties.

Second way if you want more control over how your canvas should behave then you can use Canvas Render Mode - "World Space" and then using script you can handle canvas a some gameobject.